# Android Handler and delegate functions

Tags: android, notifications, handler

I have 2 different classes in 2 separate file, now i want class B to notify class A to do an action.  Based on my understanding of Android the handler is created in the main thread  and doing the processing once the message is received. However, in order to notify class A, Class B needs that handler which is created in class A, in this case its mHandler. Also Class B activity is launched from Class A activity through New Intent and StartActivity. But if I want the handler from A passed to B, how I can accomplish that?

Instead of passing handler to create this delegate function, is there a simpler way to do, like notifcation, would that be easier?If it's How I can send the notification from B to A and in A, do the processing of notification?

In  Class A

```
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { //message sent from Class B

        String event = msg.what;
        switch(event){
        /.......

        }  //switch
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }  //handle
};
```

In Class B

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    m.what = MESSAGE;
                    mHandler.sendMessage(m); //mHandler from Class A
                }
```